# Find the fastest path through this Brazilian concretist poem

Tags: mathematics, optimization, poetry

One day, a small jet was flying over the concretist poem "Velocidade" (Speed), by the Brazilian poet Ronaldo Azeredo.

In order to cover every vowel present in this poem, it goes *in straight line* from one letter to another either orthogonally or diagonally adjacent, never making a turn sharper than 45 degrees*.

Assuming the letters are like points in a square lattice, and the jet travels at constant speed, what is the fastest way this can be achieved by the pilot?

[image: Velocidade - Ronaldo Azeredo]

Notice that no restrictions were placed in where the jet should start, except that its position goes from one letter to another. Also, the jet is not allowed to leave the matrix of letters.

* Measured by the external angle, i.e. deviation from the original path, so that a 0 degree turn leads to the same direction, while a 180 degree turn makes the jet go in the reverse.

Comment: ...Where does the pilot begin?

Comment: Can the plane leave the square once it has entered?

Comment: You'd have to end on the E at the bottom-right corner, because otherwise there's no way for you to turn out of it.

Comment: OP doesn't say it's not allowed to use vowels several times. (This would not be solvable otherwise.)

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to mention that you must go in straight line from one letter to another, eliminating the possibility of travelling outside the square. Also, @JoeZ. is correct, once you reach that corner, you can't turn back fast enough. This implies that you should either start or end there (by reversibility).

Comment: @warspyking The pilot can start and end anywhere, as long as it is able to fly through every vowel. See my edit.

Comment: You want the fastest route, so I assume horizontal/vertical travels (length 1) are faster than diagonal (length 1.41..). Is this right?

Comment: Do you mean "sharper than 135 degrees"? All your answers seem to heed this constraint.

Comment: Yes, just measuring the external angles. I think they're default in this situation, since a turn of $\alpha$ degrees followed by a turn of $\beta$ degrees results in a turn of $\alpha+\beta$ degrees if defined in this way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a solution with

> 54 steps.
> $38 \space horizontal/vertical + 16 \space diagonal => length \space 60.627$
> Thanks to  f'' for length optimization.
> [image]

A brute-forced solution with

> 47 steps.
> $28 \space horizontal/vertical + 19 \space diagonal => length \space 54.87$
> [image]

Comment: With three extra vowel touches in this one, do you think hypothetically there _should_ be a solution with 51, or is that not guaranteed?

Comment: @lorimer I think the extra vowels are no more different than the consonants. It's possible there is a better solution.

Comment: It looks like you have a 90 degree turn at the bottommost 'O'

Comment: You can save 4(sqrt2-1) by changing the triple crossing to three vertical lines.

Comment: @Sconibulus These are 2 different turns, one from left to top right, and one from right to top left.

Comment: You can also save another 2(sqrt2-1) by changing the LC/OO crossing in the lower middle to two horizontal segments.

Comment: @f'' Right, thanks, will change it.

Comment: This is a very pretty looking solution!

Answer (score 4):

OK. Touching every vowel once, using coordinates A-J horizontal and 0-9 vertically, with the origin in the top left:

> `J9->J1, I0, H0->A7, A8, B9->H9`
>  `I9->I2, H1, G1->B6, B7, C8->G8`
>  `H7->H3, G2, F2->C5, C6, D7->F7`
>  `G6->G4, F3->D3, C4, C5, D6->E6, F5`

That's 71 steps. It's probably not optimized perfectly, so I'll keep looking, but it's at least a starting point.

EDIT: This one has 59 but touches some vowels more than once. Counting as distance (cf. Sleafar's comment) it would be 68.11 units with 22 diagonal moves.

> `J9->J1, I0, H0, G1, G2, H3, I4->I8`
>  `H9->B9, A8, A7, B6, C6->E8->G8, H7`
>  `H7->H5, G4, F4->C7, C8, D9, E9, F8`
>  `F7->I4->I2, H1, G1, F2->F5, E6`
>
>  [image: Picture n' stuff]
>
>  This one doesn't waste as much time by avoiding U-turns, but instead grabs what it can that's nearby.
>
>  ETA3: nevermind, the edit would have missed one 'E'. i'll quit second-guessing myself now

Answer (score -2):

> I think I am missing something obvious, since the solution couldn't be that easy

16 diagonal + 16 vertical/horizontal steps.

> [image]

Comment: "never making a turn sharper than 45 degrees"

Comment: where? I am brain-dead here, and can see only 90 degrees and 135 degrees

Comment: Since this point has been brought up before, I edited my post to clarify it